# javascript validation for php form

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

> How can i validate this form before submitting it to php 
>   eg: if i do not enter the name and clicks submitt, the item gets saved in the
>   database

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Add Student</title>
</head>
<body  bgcolor="#192C3D" text="white">
<center>
<h2>Enter Student Details</h2><br><br>
<form action="student_add.php" method="post">
 Register no:  
 <input type="text" name="reg_no"><br><br>
 Name:
 <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
 Gender:
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M">Male
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F">Female
 <br><br>Group:
 <select name="group" size="1">
  <option value="Computer Science" selected>Computer Science</option>
  <option value="Biology">Biology</option>
  <option value="Commerce">Commerce</option>
  <option value="Humanities">Humanities</option>
 </select><br><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Save">&nbsp
 <input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

> And this is
>
> #### *student_add.php*

```html
<html>
<head><title>Add Student</title></head>
<body  bgcolor="#192C3D" text="white" alink="#75EA7E" vlink="#75EA7E" link="#75EA7E">
<a href="add_student.php"><h3>Add Student</h3></a>
<a href="Show_student.php"><h3>Show Students</h3></a>

<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "rootuser", "githin");
 
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 
// Escape user inputs for security
$reg_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['reg_no']);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['name']);
$gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['gender']);
$batch = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['group']);
 
// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO student (reg_no, name, gender, batch) VALUES ('$reg_no', '$name', '$gender', '$batch')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
 echo 'alert("Record Successfully Added")';
 echo '</script>';
} else{
     echo '<script language="javascript">';
 echo 'alert("Record Could NOT be added Successfully" . mysqli_error($link))';
 echo '</script>';
}
 
// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

> Anyone please help me to validate the above form
>   The name, reg_no and gender fields are mandatory
>   if we try to submit the form without entering the mandatory fields, a javascript alert() should be appeared asking to fill the mandatory fields

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Best not to rely on form validation which is enforced client-side whether it be via html5 or javascript. Someone could use an older browser, or disable JS (if you have a JS validation schema), or could send a `cURL` command to your site and bypass your html validation, so you need to take advantage of functions like `trim()`, `empty()`, `isset()`, `preg_match()`, `filter_var()`, etc. server-side. Client-side validation is more of a UX feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `html5` validation here, you can find updated code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Add Student</title>
</head>
<body  bgcolor="#192C3D" text="white">
<center>
<h2>Enter Student Details</h2><br><br>
<form action="student_add.php" method="post">
 Register no:  
 <input type="number" name="reg_no" required><br><br>
 Name:
 <input type="text" name="name" required><br><br>
 Gender:
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" checked>Male
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F">Female
 <br><br>Group:
 <select name="group" size="1"  required>
  <option value="Computer Science" selected>Computer Science</option>
  <option value="Biology">Biology</option>
  <option value="Commerce">Commerce</option>
  <option value="Humanities">Humanities</option>
 </select><br><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Save">&nbsp
 <input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you. Can u please help me to accept only numerical values to reg_no

Comment: Can u please help me to accept only numerical values to reg_no

Comment: just add `type="number"` instead of `type="text"`

Comment: you can also use this in your input tag `required onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'` to get rid of the arrow buttons

Comment: can you please help to avoid -ve integers

Comment: for this you can pass ` min="1" max="5"` attribute as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a versatile plugin for validation you may use http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/ . Using this plugin is safer than using HTML5 validation.